# Calling the new operator on an argument passed into a function

Tags: c++, tree, new-operator

From my understanding of C++, any variable initialized with the `new"` operator will be stored on the heap (assuming heap memory was successfully allocated) until a corresponding "delete" is called, in contrast to local variables that are only available for the scope of its containing block.

```
Node* BTree::insertIntoTree(Node* node, int value) {
   Node* newNode;
   if (node == NULL) {
      newNode = new Node(value);
   } else {
      if (value <= node->myValue) {
          newNode = insertIntoTree(node->leftChild, value);
      } else {
          newNode = insertIntoTree(node->rightChild, value);
      }   
   }   
   return newNode;
}


void BTree::insert(int value) {
    Node* newNode;
    newNode = insertIntoTree(root, value);
    return;
}
```

In my code, I'm trying to insert a node into a Binary Tree.  I do so by traversing the tree recursively and initializing the to-be-inserted node with a "new" operator.   I then return the address of this newly inserted node back up the recursion chain.  However, when I try to traverse the tree and print all the values, my tree is still empty even after I call insertIntoTree multiple times, begging me to believe that I am misuing the new operator.

I changed the implementation to below, which worked successfully for the case when my tree is empty and a new node is inserted as the root.  However, I still can't get any of the root node's leaf nodes initialized.  My question is, how come the node being initialized with the "new" constructor inside **insertIntoTree(Node* node, int value)** isn't working as I expected?

```
void BTree::insert(int value) {
    Node* newNode;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        root = new Node(value); 
    } else {
        newNode = insertIntoTree(root, value);
    } 
    return;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Hey all,

I just changed my code to the following:

```
void BTree::insertIntoTree(Node* node, int value) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = new Node(value);
    } else {
        if (value <= node->myValue) {
            insertIntoTree(node->leftChild, value);
        } else {
            insertIntoTree(node->rightChild, value);
        }   
    }   
    return;
}

void BTree::insert(int value) {
    insertIntoTree(root, value);
    return;
}
```

The code still doesn't run as expected, and I get a segmentation fault everytime I try to read the value of any of my nodes that have been inserted into the tree.  If I'm calling the new operator on my node argument, shouldn't that dynamically allocate memory to that node argument?

Comment: I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but you're attempting something too far above your current skill to be a useful exercise. You must go back and play around with variables and pointers, and **passing by reference versus passing by value**, using the simplest examples you can devise, or none of this will get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in this code you assigning anything to these fields:

```
node->leftChild
node->rightChild
```

So you are creating nodes, but they are just unlinked. 
In your 2nd version of the code, root gets assigned, but again remaining nodes end up unlinked.

For example, 
1st time you call insert(int value), root gets created and function returns

2nd time you call insert(int value),

- insertIntoTree(Node* node, value) gets called with node=root,
- and in turn you call one more time recursively insertIntoTree(Node* node, value), this time with node=null
- you create a new node, and return it
- recursively return the same node
- and at the end you assign it to newNode inside insert function
  at the end newNode just gets leaked, since it is not assigned to anything inside the tree

Comment: Hey there, I removed the newNode variable and now I'm trying to initialize the node argument passed into insertIntoTree() directly.  Could you please take a look at the updates I made to my question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Node* BTree::insertIntoTree(Node* node, int value) {
   if (node == NULL) {
      node = new Node(value);
   } else {
      if (value <= node->myValue) {
         // This makes sure that node->leftChild gets a new Node
         // when it is NULL. If it is not NULL, the assignment is a
         // noop.
          node->lefChild = insertIntoTree(node->leftChild, value);
      } else {
         // This makes sure that node->rightChild gets a new Node
         // when it is NULL. If it is not NULL, the assignment is a
         // noop.
          node->rightChild = insertIntoTree(node->rightChild, value);
      }   
   }   
   return node;
}

void BTree::insert(int value) {
    // This makes sure that root gets a new Node
    // when it is NULL. If it is not NULL, the assignment is a
    // noop.
    root = insertIntoTree(root, value);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work out for me.  My issue is that when initializing the node argument passed into insertIntoTree(node, value), the node doesn't seem to get initialized.  I have made updates to my question and they can be found above - your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By inspection your code would appear to work all the way down and back up to `insert`. And then:

```
void BTree::insert(int value) {
  Node* newNode;
  newNode = insertIntoTree(root, value);
  return;
}
```

After the call to `insertIntoTree`, The pointer `newNode` points to the newly created node. Then control passes out of `insert`, the pointer passes out of scope, and the node is lost.

Comment: Hey there, I took your suggestion and implemented a new function which I have included in my previous question under the "update" section.  Could you please take a look?  Thank you!